# sfdc.keystone.catalog.core.impl.StorePools$ExtentInNoStoreException Error

Tags: apex, sales

Has anyone come across this error? The only clue I had were exception emails received and had the following detail:

> Developer script exception from Org : 'InvoiceUtility' :
>   sfdc.keystone.catalog.core.impl.StorePools$ExtentInNoStoreException:
>   there are no stores that currently contain the extent=
>   F00D90000000i7650KE5L000000MD1G1, so we can't read it!
>
> ApexApplication  Thu 6/6, 9:19 AM
>
> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization:
>   00590000003yqKe/00D90000000XXXX
>        Failed to invoke future method 'public static void generateInvoice(Set)' on class 'InvoiceUtility' for job id
>   '7075L000000JI2K'

I was combing the 'net for what this could be, but no luck. It seems to be generated along with a 500 status code return error and a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. I'm treating them all as related but would anyone have an idea of what's happening? Thanks.

Comment: This error is internal. I'd suggest opening a case with Salesforce Support for assistance understanding and troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question - Salesforce support came back with the following:

> I've verified this with the help of the server logs at my end and I believe this should've been an issue from our end which could be specific to your Org or server. It seems like this issue got auto resolved and hence the errors didn't show up again at your end.
>
> However, as of now there is no issue from our end and the above seem
>   have got resolved and as a result you aren't facing any issues.
>
> Moving forward, if you face any such errors consistently, please do
>   report us immediately so that we can take this to the notice of our
>   R&D to get this fixed promptly.

So it looks to me that this is an issue that will have to be dealt with Salesforce but it's looking like a server issue at their end. Best to escalate with them directly at the first onset of the problem for Salesforce support to catch it happening.